# Bash Awk command confusion

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I was checking a piece of code and I can't fully understand it:

```
var1=`awk -F , '{printf "%.0f\n", $1*17/1000}' $somefile`;
```

Let's say that the number it receives from the file is 1000, it multiplies it by 17 and divides by 1000, but before that, there's this: `"%.0f\n"`
I know how rest of the calculations go, but that part confuses me.
As far as I understand it, it's calculating a desimal of something and prints a newline.
An answer with a pit of explanation of the awk command in whole would be appreciated :D

Comment: Did you even read the manual and look at the `printf` function?

Comment: Yes and that's why I'm so confused, it explained nothing

Comment: It actually explains everything! the `"%.0f"` is the format (it's called fmt in my man page). Then going down to the _printf Statement_ section, I see that `%f` is the format for _A floating point number_. Below this I read _additional  parameters may lie between the % and the control letter_ and a bit below I see: `.prec  A number that specifies the precision to use when printing. For the  %e,  %E,  %f  and %F, formats, this specifies the number of digits you want printed to the right of the decimal point.` Are you sure you even read the manual?

Comment: We've read different manuals my friend :D Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @BonBon you must've been reading the manual for your microwave because not only does every awk manual I've ever seen clearly explain `printf`, but `printf` is common to MANY programming languages and functions the same way in all of them!

Comment: @BonBon Good thing for you is that (as Ed Morton says) once you learn `printf`, you don't have to learn it again. `printf` [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string). Most docs actually cover it in unnecessary detail.

Comment: actually I have seen some awk manuals simply state that printf uses the same formatting as in C. Then you need to know to do `man 3 printf` which is not an easy read. Probably a reason why on linux the printf explanations are in the awk man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets the number of decimal points to zero (truncates the number) after the computation.  You can find more information [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html#Control-Letters)

You can try it out yourself by typing

```
awk -F, '{printf "%.0f\n", $1*17/1000}'
```

on the command line, it will then convert your input for each entered line, but perhaps this will be more intuitive.  (Control-D to exit)

```
awk -F, '{printf "%.0f\n", $1}'
```

ps. Note that this is equivalent to integer formatting %d or %i (no decimal points)

Comment: Thanks :D But that website link of yours doesn't work: http:// www.awk -f , '{printf "%25.0f\n", $1*17/1000}' I don't think Awk works with that format ;)

Comment: you should have `awk` installed locally, also uppercase F not lowercase,

Comment: Ooops, sorry fixed link.